# ASP.NET CustomError redirect 404 doesn't return 404 code in Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How can I make it return a custom ASP.NET page with an error code of 404? Currently it doesn't do that when I set the

```
<customErrors mode="On">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/UtahDisclosures.aspx" />
        </customErrors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of ASP.NET and one that I was unnaware of before reading your post.

However, a quick Google turned up this blog post: http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/57/getting-the-correct-http-status-codes-out-of-asp.net-custom-error-pages

They seem to know what they're on about and suggest using this:
`<% Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound; %>` along with some other key steps (see the link).

Also, when sending custom error pages, you might need to bear this [IE minimum error page size quirk](http://perishablepress.com/important-note-for-your-custom-error-pages/) in mind.